# Import/export data in Adempiere

Tags: erp, adempiere

I am quite new to Adempiere. I want to ask if Adempiere have any adapter to help import/export data from other app like excel, sql or sugarcrm ... ? May an interface or API that we can use or extend from would be ok as well. Also can Adempiere communicate with calendar like outlook or google calendar? Thank you for your input

Answer (score 2):

I hope the following help..
"import/export data from other app like excel"
http://wiki.adempiere.net/Data_Import

"May an interface or API that we can use"

http://wiki.adempiere.net/Adempiere_Web_Services

regards..